# search for latest image inside a folder, and save it as a png file with python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to do some image analysis using the python on Raspberry Pi.

I am streaming images using motion to a folder. In that folder, I want to find the latest image at any point of time. Then I would like to apply my image analysis command on that one image and export the results to a text file. I have achieved most parts of it. But struck at one small bit.

```
import subprocess
import os
import glob
newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[p][n][g]'), key=os.path.getctime)
print(newest)

cmd = "sudo ./deepbelief  lena.png  > try5.txt"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

In the above deepbelief is my image analysis program. Now the problem is how can I feed my newest image as input to the command ./deepbelief.

Also, if possible, can I save   newest image as an png file for later use?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: where so you want to save the png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

```
cmd = "sudo ./deepbelief  {}  > try5.txt".format(newest)
```

The `{}` will be whatever the value of newest is, so for example if newest  is foo.png, you're command will be   `"sudo ./deepbelief  foo.png > try5.txt"` and so on..

Comment: Thanks a million Padriac. You saved my day! I am able to get what I intended to get!